# Alternate word for "Request Handler"

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a substitute word for *RequestHandler*. I come across this word as the name of a class while working on pre-written code.

---

P.S.:

1. I know that the best name would depend on the context for which the class is created (or the context in which the entity exists). However, this name is very commonly used, so I'm looking for a commonly substitutable word.
2. Please feel free to write your suggestion even if it looks out of the place for now. Reason: the word may be the perfect substitute in some other code setting. The suggestion *Slave*  given below is absolutely not the word I'm looking for but this can be the perfectly abstracting word for code written for Master-Slave architectures.

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't want to use the straightforward/common term _request handler_?

Comment: @alwayslearning: Class names in OOProgramming should be nouns, like Browser, Page, Frame etc. - _RequestHandler_ is not even a word. In the presence of correct word, _RequestHandler_ will look like half-hearted effort from a programmer with limited vocabulary. Hence, searching for an alternate.

Comment: @alwayslearning: To disclose fully, I'm working on legacy code which has this monolithic _RequestHandler_ class. If I don't get a good word I will just perform the other refactorings and leave the name be.

Comment: @alwayslearning: One last addition :-) ...  I've always promoted and respected the creation of new words/phrases etc (you can see that for yourself in my earlier questions/answers on EL&U). But, before I go ahead and leave _RequestHandler_ unchanged, I want to make sure that I have evaluated currently existing words and suggestions from the community. To be frank, I'm quite hopeful somebody will suggest a good word that has not been considered yet.

Comment: As a fellow programmer plus an English language enthusiast, I respectfully disagree. _Request handler_ is a competent term being a compound noun and you use RequestHandler only because you cannot embed a space in a class name. Whoever is judging your vocabulary based on this is either a non-programmer or just being overpedantic. Nothing wrong in trying to _improve_ it, though.

Comment: As @alwayslearning says, "RequestHandler" is a perfectly valid, and understood, class name. Unless you _know_ what kind of request you're handling and how you're handling it (say XmlToJsonParser), I think you're pretty much fine. You could easily add a little more onto it, like PostRequestHandler or something.

Comment: @alwayslearning: The other commonly seen (bad) class name is _DatabaseManager_ which is also a compound noun. Its substitute is simply _Database_. _RequestHandler_ does not have that easy to identify substitute. And I'm not judging anyway by how they name classes, but a good OOCode which has been given sufficient attention in the designing phase will have very few such names.

Comment: @VampDuc: Yes, _RequestHandler_ is valid. I want to look at the options before I leave it be.

Comment: How about the rest of my comment? What are you requesting and how are you handling it? Do you know the answers to those questions?

Comment: @VampDuc: The complete name of the class I'm working on is _SpatialImportRequestHandler_. The class processes spatial data import requests on a High Performance Computing (HPC) cluster. If I get a good substitute to _RequestHandler_, I will deduce the name for entire _SpatialImportRequestHandler_. I felt that asking for a general substitute (to _RequestHandler_) as opposed to highly context specific substitute (to _SpatialImportRequestHandler_) will not restrict answers to my specific context and will be useful to more people.

Comment: Well, then I think your question is a bit flawed: _RequestHandler_ is a common, accepted, and valid class name. It __should__ be replaced with a more specific and descriptive classname, but, in small programming projects or those that get tacked on endlessly, naming a single class _RequestHandler_ that handles __all__ requests is fine.

Comment: @VampDuc: _DatabaseManager_, just like  _RequestHandler_, is fairly common, accepted and valid class name. I have seen both these names in numerous projects. The compiler makes no noise about compiling projects with such names. But I have already given the better substitute for _DatabaseManager_ above. If I get an answer for my question, I'll consider myself lucky.

Comment: I think you might get better answers on http://stackoverflow.com. But I'm not sure about their guidelines on asking this type of question.

Comment: @VampDuc: Try posting the question there - you can earn all the rep. I'm pretty sure if I post this question there, I'll be booted out of the community and arrested by SO Police. :D

Comment: Heh. Possibly you'll like _"Processor"_? Does not get any more common than that.

Comment: Certainly it would seem to depend on the type of request whether it's a *gatekeeper*, *processor*, *arbiter*, *archivist*, *curator*, whatever.

Comment: @stevesliva: That is absolutely true. Still, using the right word in the right context would only make the code easier to understand. You can add the suggestions as an answer and slightly explain the scenario where each word should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Slave may work, depending on if the 'RequestHandler' has autonomy or simply acts indiscriminately on the requests it receives.

## Slave

> 7. A machine or component controlled by another machine or component.
>    [free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slave)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you might like "[***Processor***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/processor)"? Terminology does not get any more common than that...

> a machine, company, etc., that treats, prepares, or handles something

Reference:
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/processor